# Some users can't talk to my action

Tags: actions-on-google

I did this test action https://assistant.google.com/services/a/uid/0000004495870842?hl=en

Console says that is published and that it has 300 users weekly but when I ask some of my friends no one can talk to the action, and if they follow the link don't see anything.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8iOZ.png)

All of us are in Spain. Is there any restriction by country? I can access and use it, but I'm the developer.

thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Overview section in Actions on Google console, the step number 3. is Location targeting, make sure that you have Spain turned on.

Edit: 
Adding translations in AoG console for requiered languages solves this problem.

Comment: Yes, it is. My configuration of Location targeting is "All 213 countries (recommended)".

Comment: Okay, are your phones and your friends phones in English or Spanish?

Comment: Ok, that's the problem. Mine is in English and if I change the language to Spanish and follow the link to the actions catalog, I can't see anything.

It is really strange behavior, but I suppose that adding a translation to Spanish will solve it. I'll inform you. Thank you.

Comment: The action is made with a Trivia template, and it seems that this template is not ready to manage Spanish actions so I can't add a Spanish translation, but I can add French, German, Japanese... so I think that the problem is it. Thank you very much for your support Denis.